# Linq to Sql - Convert C# to VB.NET help

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm having trouble converting a C# Linq statement to VB.NET.  I need the following statement converted.  I am getting hung up on the i.Sum(v=>v) part.

```
from p in Products
from u in Users
let i = (from op in OrderProducts
         where op.Order.User == u && op.Product == p
         select op.ProductQty)
let quant = i.Count() == 0 ? 0 : i.Sum(v=>v)
select new {p.ProductName, u.UserName, Quantity = quant}
```

Here's what I have for VB, but the If(i.Count() = 0, 0, i.Sum()) _ statement says Parameterless aggregate operator 'Sum' is not supported over projections during runtime (no compile time errors).  I have also tried i.Sum(Function(q) i.ProductQty) which doesn't work either (says sum cannot be called with these arguments).

```
From p In Products _
From u In Users _
Let i = (From op In OrderProducts _
         Where op.Order.User.UserID = u.UserID And op.Product.ProductID = p.ProductID _
         Select op.ProductQty) _
Let Qty = _
         If(i.Count() = 0, 0, i.Sum()) _
Select New With {p.ProductName, u.Username, Qty}
```

Any ideas on how to get that converted to VB.NET and working?  Thanks!

Comment: Note that if you want an accurate translation, `&&` in C# is equivalent to `AndAlso` not `And`. Similarly `||` is equivalent to `OrElse` not `Or`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your "arrow" syntax in C#:

```
.Sum(v => v)
```

Can be converted to the following in VB.NET:

```
.Sum(Function(v) v)
```

The "arrow" syntax is a lambda expression.  For more info on Lambda Expressions in VB.NET, check out [this MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx).

Comment: FYI, it's called a lambda expression.

Comment: Yup.  Assumed the OP wouldn't know lambdas, but good to note the correct name in there.